# convert values in a javascript map to all strings

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I am looking for a good way to convert a javascript map values in a way that all be string type. Originally I have this dataObject :

```
dataObject: 
errorCode: "notFound"
timeOutLen: 5
validUrl: false
numRequest: 0
```

which I converted to map by this:

```
const datamap = new Map(Object.entries(dataObject))
```

now for some reason down the line, the external code I am using is throwing exception because of some values like 0 or false in map values. I would like to change all the values in map to be string and be like this so I can pass this exception for logging purposes:

```
new dataObject: 
    errorCode: "notFound"
    timeOutLen: "5"
    validUrl: "false"
    numRequest: "0"
```

Can you please help me to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution:

```
const dataMap = new Map();
for (const k in dataObject)
    dataMap.set(k, String(dataObject[p]));
```

The single-expression-solution:

```
const dataMap = new Map(Object.entries(dataObject).map(([k, v]) => [k, String(v)]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the String() function to convert values to String.

```
const dataMap = new Map();
Object.keys(dataObject).forEach(key => {
    dataMap.set(key, String(dataObject[key]));
});

console.log(dataMap);
```